# ContactsContract returning this string content://com.android.contacts/data/1 not the phone number from contact list

Tags: java, android, contactscontract

I copy the code example from the from Beginning Android™ Application Development Book.
The code is use to display the contact list according to phone number on my app as user click the button. The code works fine as I comment the `// startActivity(i); on  onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) function` I got the following string

> content://com.android.contacts/data/1

but I wanted to get the phone number from my contact list. For this purpose I am using the following code.

```
public OnClickListener addContactButtonListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.v(TAG, "addContactButtonListener  ");
        Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        i.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE);
        startActivityForResult(i, 1);


    }
};

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.v(TAG, "onActivityResult");

    if (requestCode == 1) {
        Log.v(TAG, "onActivityResult > requestCode " + requestCode);

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Log.v(TAG, "onActivityResult > resultCode " + resultCode);
            Toast.makeText(this, data.getData().toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            queryEditText.setText(data.getData().toString());
            Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse(data.getData().toString()));

            Log.v(TAG, "onActivityResult > startActivity " + i.toString());

            startActivity(i);
        }
    }
}
```

but on un-commenting `startActivity(i);`  I got following errors

```
11-09 23:09:37.913: V/MyApp_Main(4002): onActivityResult > startActivity Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=content://com.android.contacts/data/1 }
11-09 23:09:37.923: D/AndroidRuntime(4002): Shutting down VM
11-09 23:09:37.923: W/dalvikvm(4002): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
11-09 23:09:37.933: E/AndroidRuntime(4002): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-09 23:09:37.933: E/AndroidRuntime(4002): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.contacts/data/1 flg=0x1 (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.MyApp/com.example.MyApp.MyApp_Main}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=content://com.android.contacts/data/1 }
11-09 23:09:37.933: E/AndroidRuntime(4002):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2532)
11-09 23:09:37.933: E/AndroidRuntime(4002):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:2574)
11-09 23:09:37.933: E/AndroidRuntime(4002):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:117)
11-09 23:09:37.933: E/AndroidRuntime(4002):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:961)
```

**Can anybody explain what what is going on here?**

Comment: Please state your question clearly...

Comment: I edit my question. Hope my question is clear now and you can easily find the error to help me out.